# What are the necessary files for creating a bootable remastered ISO?

Tags: iso, puppy-linux

I've modified my version of puppy and created  new (remastered) .sfs file 
I created the new .sfs file with:

```
mksquashfs puppyfilesystem myRelease/puppy-remastered.sfs -noappend
```

So far so fine, but the next step is a bit confusing. I need to create an .ISO so that I can then boot from CD.

According to the documentation the command for this is:

```
mkisofs -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -D -l -R -v -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o "puppy_remaster.iso" myRelease
```

What I find confusing though is that I need to copy any necessary files into the myRelease folder before this.

Thus my question is: What ARE these necessary files?